# Different colours with no texture

Tags: rendering

I'm using cycles render and I was making a wine glass but I finished the basic shape and there is something weird about it. I see a brighter colour where there is no vertex and I didn't add any textures. (I'm a beginner at Bleder)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from just a photo. Did you check your UVs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this shading is due to your lighting. The sun lamp you have is casting light rays straight down. If you look closely, the light areas are the areas that receive light, and the dark areas are shadowed.

If you want more even light, try a hemi lamp (I find these to be great for quick, even lighting) or rotate your sun lamp a bit and add a floor plane so the light can reflect and bounce around some more, which will also give some better lighting.